# django - returning user extended fields when creating user

Tags: json, django, dictionary, serialization

**I am extending the auth.user Model:**

Modles.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Here is my UserSerializer.

When I create the user, I am able to update its `userprofile` field, but I can't figure out how to add it to the serialized user and return the **user fields+the extended field**.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', )
        read_only_fields = ('phone_number', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            username=validated_data['username'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        user.userprofile.phone_number = self.initial_data["phone_number"]
        user.userprofile.save()
        the_dict = {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'first_name': user.first_name,
            'last_name': user.last_name,
            'phone_number': user.userprofile.phone_number
        }

        return the_dict
```

As you can see, I am trying to add it somehow to the dictionary, but in my client I only get the user fields ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name').

How can I add the phone_number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # source is required to show where this field is coming from
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.phone_number')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Add phone_number to the fields
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'phone_number', )
        read_only_fields = ('phone_number', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

I commented the code above to explain.

Comment: Yeah I just found  that after posting the question.  It works great